# Controls size issues of C# windows form, looks different on compile time and different in Run Time

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, controls

I have some weird problem, I am setting controls location according to requirement as well as adding new controls, but when I build project and run it, It looks totally different, all controls position location have been changed. This problem occurred when I started work on different resolution windows machine. Now if I copy this project, any windows system it looks same.
I am sharing two screen shot.

This image shown, when I set the control location according my requirement.
[image]

this image shown status of control when I run the application.
[image]

I hope you will understand this problem.

Comment: Based on the picture you provided. If the winform app is developed in other computer, it is possible to occur the problem. You could set your [AutoScaleMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.autoscalemode?view=net-5.0) to Dpi to adapt the computer.

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT  yes. it works...thanks.

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, I have made an answer and you can click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the picture you provided, If the winform app is developed in other computer, it is possible to occur the problem.

You could set your [AutoScaleMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.autoscalemode?view=net-5.0) to Dpi to adapt the computer.

```
this.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Dpi;
```